# Is there a way of using the useState hook to toggle className in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a vertical ellipsis, whereby users can click on it (toggle) and select the actions they want to perform.

However, i understand that directly manipulating the DOM in react is not allowed. Because trying to toggle a classList  throws the error -  TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null.

How can I make use of the useState hook to add/remove a className on toggle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Standard fair:

```
const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState(false)

return <div className={toggleClass ? 'some-class' : ''} />
```

Using template literals:

```
const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState(false)

return <div className={`some-class ${toggleClass ? 'some-class' :''}`} />
```

Using the popular [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) package:

```
import cx from 'classnames'

const Component = () => {
    const [toggleClass, setToggleClass] = useState(false)

    return <button className={cx('btn', {
        'btn--primary': toggleClass
    })}>Submit</button>

}
```

Comment: This definitely helped for what I intended to implement. Thanks!